# Value of form field set via JavaScript is not passed to PHP script as part of $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

I am having some trouble figuring out a way to pass a javascripts value to a .php script, and then from there to a .txt script.

When doing this with a regular number it works, but when I want to do it with the variable which it has to be, the .txt file is left blank and nothing has been added to the file. I have searched the web "dry" for options, and I just can't figure out how to make it work. currently my scripts look like below and

I believe that is the right way of doing it, there is just some problem with it as I said, and as I also said I believe the mistake is in the part from the javascript file to the .php file.

### javascript/html:

```
<form id="pg-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="pg-form">
<input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
<input type="hidden" id="curValueField" value=""/> <!-- this is where I am trying to pass the value -->
<input type="image"  src="pgBut1.png" id="pgBut" value="submit" alt="butPG"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

    return true;
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    window.onload(function(){
    var currentVarValue = 1; //this is the variable value I am trying to pass
    document.getElementById("currentVarValue").innerHTML = currentVarValue;
    document.getElementById("curValueField").value = currentVarValue;   //this is where I get the variable value and make the new id to get in the html form        
});
</script>
```

### php:

```
<?php 

    require_once('./stripe-php/init.php');

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("removed for security");

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $myAmount = $_POST['amount'];
    $describtion = $_POST['description'];

    $curValue= $_POST['curValueField']; //this is where I try to get the variable value

    $myAmount = round((int)$myAmount*100,0);

    try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $myAmount,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $describtion));

    //pass value to .txt file start
    $filename = "getVarValue.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content .= $curValue;
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
    //pass value to .txt file end       

    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your curValueField doesn't have a name, so its value is never sent to your PHP.

Try this :

```
<input type="hidden" id="curValueField" name="curValueField" value=""/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have figured out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to "name",
try

```
<input type="hidden" id="curValueField" name="curValueField" value=""/>
```

And to `.txt`, can try below code

```
$fp = fopen("test.txt", "a"); 
if($fp) { 
    fwrite($fp,$msg);
}   
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: That has been suggested already. And the OP's file writing code looks ok, doesn't it?

Comment: "When doing this with a regular number it works" look like it works. But it can be interesting for the OP.